# Software updater won't launch

Tags: updates, update-manager, 17.04, synaptic

I am having trouble while launching software updater software won't update and a Red minus icon appears in the home launch bar.

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in a terminal window?

Comment: I accidentaly removed python3 that is causing problem..how should i fix it

Comment: Does `sudo apt install python3` work?

Comment: it works...but the problem is still there..my terminals wont open through shortcut ,update manager wont open

Comment: Try rebooting to see if the changes take effect.  If that doesn't help you might have removed more than just python3 and might have to reinstall your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a software updater from a command line (in the application named terminal, but in GNOME you can run it using a shortcut too, as shown below.).

I will write an example based on your case of the need to reinstall python3 package.

Press: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3
```

If lacking python3 package is your problem, hopefully this will help.  Please let me know if it worked, because there are a couple of ways to try if you're still stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working..

Comment: (I understand it's Ubuntu 17.04.) Do you use Unity (a default GUI) or another GUI?

Comment: I have Unity as my gui . I accidentaly removed python3 from /usr/lib/ python3 so is it causing problem?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if someone is trying to launch the GUI version of the update manager, this is the command to run in command line: `update-manager`
More info on this software: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-manager.8.html